# Converting Json data in array format to a list with type as dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

[This image shows the output ,i am trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU3Il.png)I have a Json gz file with couple of records as below

```
data=

[{ "eventName" : "App Installed" , "ts" : 20190915002057 , "eventProps" : { "CT Source" : "Mobile" , "ct_app_version" : "1.3.93"} , "profile" : { "all_identities" : [ "3512631"] , "identity" : "3512631" , "platform" : "Android" , "phone" : 919945966964 , "name" : "SHIVAKUMAR B S"} , "deviceInfo" : { "osVersion" : "9" , "sdkVersion" : "30402" , "make" : "Xiaomi" , "model" : "Redmi Note 5 Pro" , "appVersion" : "1.3.93" , "browser" : "MobileApp" , "dpi" : 440 , "dimensions" : { "width" : 68 , "height" : 127 , "unit" : "mm"}}},

{ "eventName" : "App Installed" , "ts" : 20190915002818 , "eventProps" : { "CT Source" : "Mobile" , "ct_app_version" : "1.3.93"} , "profile" : { "all_identities" : [ "3497362"] , "identity" : "3497362" , "platform" : "Android" , "phone" : 919861231341 , "name" : "P K Sharma" , "push_token" : "fcm:f3hX8xbV5AU:APA91bETNmb4f77Z4qdPC3yDTXz5f3HwUlhkD0ppaxmPYb0puWwE7hOXwpg9nxN0ULZGxpItk3BTxP0sV7CT4zXN6j5BxXUyuBjfDXg7UDE3lRCiR-6Q677oRY8o6B2vITXlWLCbWsFw"} , "deviceInfo" : { "osVersion" : "7.1.1" , "sdkVersion" : "30402" , "make" : "motorola" , "model" : "Moto E (4) Plus" , "appVersion" : "1.3.93" , "browser" : "MobileApp" , "dpi" : 320 , "dimensions" : { "width" : 68 , "height" : 112 , "unit" : "mm"}}}]
```

its an array and when I import it into data as above it becomes a list with type as dict and size as 5 for each row and when expanded it becomes a combination of below
as

**AS DICT**

```
"eventProps" : { "CT Source" : "Mobile" , "ct_app_version" : "1.3.93"},

"profile" : { "all_identities" : [ "3497362"] , "identity" : "3497362" , "platform" : "Android" , "phone" : 919861231341 , "name" : "P K Sharma" , "push_token" : "fcm:f3hX8xbV5AU:APA91bETNmb4f77Z4qdPC3yDTXz5f3HwUlhkD0ppaxmPYb0puWwE7hOXwpg9nxN0ULZGxpItk3BTxP0sV7CT4zXN6j5BxXUyuBjfDXg7UDE3lRCiR-6Q677oRY8o6B2vITXlWLCbWsFw"}

"deviceInfo" : { "osVersion" : "7.1.1" , "sdkVersion" : "30402" , "make" : "motorola" , "model" : "Moto E (4) Plus" , "appVersion" : "1.3.93" , "browser" : "MobileApp" , "dpi" : 320 , "dimensions" : { "width" : 68 , "height" : 112 , "unit" : "mm"}}
```

**As STring**

```
"eventName" : "App Installed"
```

**As INt**

```
int "ts" : 20190915002057
```

how can I do the same by directly importing the .gz file without passing the rows separately

I tried as below but it gives me a list with type as string and not dict

```
import json;
import gzip
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

jsonfilename='App-Installed-20190913-0-0.json.gz'

with gzip.GzipFile(jsonfilename, 'r') as fin:
    json_bytes = fin.read()
    json_str = json_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    json_str_replace=json_str.replace("}}}","}}}*,")

    DataList= list(map(str.strip, json_str_replace.split('*,')))
```

Answer (score 0):

loads function will convert the string to json object. Is this what you want?

```
import json
import gzip

with gzip.GzipFile('test.json.gz', 'r') as fin:
    json_bytes = fin.read()
    json_str = json_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    json_data = json.loads(json_str)
    print(type(json_data))
```

output:

```
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: I tried doing it ,it gives me JSONDecodeError: Extra data  error.

Comment: I used the same array that you have posted in the question above. Did you try with that data or with some other data?